# Understanding nested flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am experimenting with flex-box but I seem to be failing to create nested flexboxes. As in the code below, while the container children behaves normally, the paragraphs in the text div do not perform as expected.

I am trying to create a row of divs (div 1 2 3) aligned horizontally spaced evenly, while the contents in the middle div (the two paragraphs) should be spaced vertically evenly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>abc</p>
      <p>def</p>
    </div>
    <div>Div 3</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.text {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  weight: 100%
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Add a proper height to the text div.

Answer (score 0):

As Paulie said you have to add a height to your text class. In addition to that make the default margin and padding of the body 0 so that you can see the evenly spaced div(s). Here is the code for the css

```
*{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .container {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            align-items: flex-start;
            
          }
          
          .text {
            height: 80px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: space-between;
            
          }
```